# QT Creator под windows не находит файл проекта (.pro)

Tags: qt4, qtcreator, c++

Что делать, если QT Creator под windows не находит файл проекта (.pro) и в лог постройки пишет следующее:

```
17:57:56: Running steps for project first...
17:57:56: Starting: "C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe" "D:\мои документы\QT\first\first.pro" -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
Cannot find file: d:\мои документы\QT\first\first.pro.
17:57:56: The process "C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project first (target: Desktop)
When executing step 'qmake'
```

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось просто - qt creator под Windows не понимает пробелов в пути к файлам

Answer (score 2):

Также он не понимает **кириллицу**, такая же ошибка была, если в пути к файлу присутствует кириллица

Comment: к проверяющим: может быть, хоть один из трёх ответов про кириллицу стоит оставить? ну, в крайнем случае, в комментарий преобразовать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin что-то не пойму, за что другие ответы были удалены.